# Remove the last-occured lines of patterns

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing

I want to exclude/delete the last line of pattern {n}{n}{n}.log for each possible 3-digit numbers. Each lines end with a sample pattern "123.log".

Sample input file:

```
aaaa116.log
a112.log
aaa112.log
a113.log
aaaaa112.log
aaa113.log
aa112.log
aaa116.log
a113.log
aaaaa116.log
aaa113.log
aa114.log
```

Output file:

```
aaaa116.log
a112.log
aaa112.log
a113.log
aaaaa112.log
aaa113.log
aaa116.log
a113.log
```

How could this be performed by bash scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly simple to remove the last matching line in `awk` without retaining order.

```
awk -F'[^0-9]+' '/[0-9]+\.log$/ {
    t = $(NF - 1);
    if (t in a)
        print a[t];
    a[t] = $0;
}'
```

To keep the output ordered is more complicated, and requires more memory.

```
awk -F'[^0-9]+' '/[0-9]+\.log$/ {
    t = $(NF - 1);
    a[++i] = $0;
    b[$0] = t;
    c[t] = i;
}
END {
    for (n = 1; n <= i; n++)
        if (n != c[b[a[n]]])
            print a[n];
}'
```

To pass through non-matching lines in the first example a `next` statement can be added to the action, and a pattern of `1` can be appended.  For the second example assignment into array `a` can be moved to its own action.

Comment: Well that worked for my sample input correctly but surprisingly not for my real data. What could I be missing to generalize this script? 



`/opt/appname/log/CL_20150820_000218_000_10015.log
/opt/appname/log/CL_20150820_001519_000_10013.log
/opt/appname/log/CL_20150820_094948_000_10016.log
/opt/appname/log/CL_20150820_120048_000_10013.log
/opt/appname/log/CL_20150821_000017_000_10013.log
/mnt/app/log/CL_20150821_140317_000_10016.log
/mnt/log/CL_20150821_140319_000_10012.log
/mnt/log/CL_20150821_171141_000_10012.log
/mnt/log/CL_20150822_000010_000_10012.log`

Comment: It is checking for uniqueness using all the digits, with a format like that things become easier for `awk`. `awk -F_ '$NF~/[0-9]+\.log$/{a[++i]=$0;b[$0]=$NF+0;c[$NF+0]=i}END{for(n=1;n<=i;n++)if(n!=c[b[a[n]]])print a[n]}'`

Answer (score 1):

Probably awk would be the easiest tool for this. For example, this one-liner

```
tac file | awk 'match($0, /[0-9]{3}.log/,a) && a[0] in b; {b[a[0]]}' | tac
```

produces the requested output for the sample input. This does not require the entire file to be stored in memory.

Change the regular expression to suit your specific needs.

Comment: @Yiğit I tested it with GNU awk (`gawk`), and it seems to work. Perhaps I am using some GNU specific syntax. Try installing GNU awk on your system and see if it works.

Comment: The 3rd arg for match() is gawk-specific. If you're ever using gawk but unsure if you're using a gawk extension or not, try running the script as `gawk --posix`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{k=substr($0,length()-7)} NR==FNR{n[k]=NR;next} FNR!=n[k]' file file
aaaa116.log
a112.log
aaa112.log
a113.log
aaaaa112.log
aaa113.log
aaa116.log
a113.log
```